# Null Reference while handling a List in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Basically, i have a collection of objects, i am chopping it into small collections, and doing some work on a thread over each small collection simultaneously.

```
int totalCount =  SomeDictionary.Values.ToList().Count;
int singleThreadCount = (int)Math.Round((decimal)(totalCount / 10));
int lastThreadCount = totalCount - (singleThreadCount * 9);

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

Dictionary<int,Thread> allThreads = new Dictionary<int,Thread>();
List<rCode> results = new List<rCode>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int count = i;

    if (i != 9)
    {
        Thread someThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            List<rBase> objects =  SomeDictionary.Values
                                          .Skip(count * singleThreadCount)
                                          .Take(singleThreadCount).ToList();

            List<rCode> result = objects.Where(r => r.ZBox != null)
            .SelectMany(r => r.EffectiveCBox, (r, CBox) => new rCode
                                {
                                    RBox = r,
                                    // A Zbox may refer an object that can be 
                                    // shared by many 
                                    // rCode objects even on different threads
                                    ZBox = r.ZBox,
                                    CBox = CBox
                                }).ToList();

            results.AddRange(result);
        });

        allThreads.Add(i, someThread);
        someThread.Start();
    }
    else 
    {
        Thread someThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            List<rBase> objects =  SomeDictionary.Values
                                           .Skip(count * singleThreadCount)
                                           .Take(lastThreadCount).ToList();

            List<rCode> result = objects.Where(r => r.ZBox != null)
            .SelectMany(r => r.EffectiveCBox, (r, CBox) => new rCode
                        {
                            RBox = r,
                            // A Zbox may refer an object that 
                            // can be shared by many 
                            // rCode objects even on different threads
                            ZBox = r.ZBox, 
                            CBox = CBox
                        }).ToList();

            results.AddRange(result);
        });

        allThreads.Add(i, someThread);
        someThread.Start();
    }
}

sw.Start();
while (allThreads.Values.Any(th => th.IsAlive))
{ 
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 60000) 
    { 
        results = null; 
        allThreads.Values.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Abort()); 
        sw.Stop(); 
        break; 
    } 
}

return  results != null ? results.OrderBy(r => r.ZBox.Name).ToList():null;
```

so, My issue is that SOMETIMES, i get a null reference exception while performing the OrderBy operation before returning the results, and i couldn't determine where is the exception exactly, i press back, click the same button that does this operation on the same data again, and it works !! .. If someone can help me identify this issue i would be more than gratefull. NOTE :A Zbox may refer an object that can be shared by many rCode objects even on different threads, can this be the issue ?
as i can't determine this upon testing, because the error happening is not deterministic.

Comment: Sounds like you have a very typical threading style bug.

Comment: Are the different threads able to alter the value of `r.ZBox` at any given time?

Comment: you are modifying the results List<> from all threads at the same time. This is a bad idea, as List<T> is not thread safe. You will never know what you will end up with when you manipulate your list like this.

Comment: Seems like you could just replace the whole thing with `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, they don't alter it, they just call it for assignment when creating the a new rCode object

Comment: @GarlandGreene Do you suggest i create a collection for each thread and then join them in the end ?

Comment: @SirajMansour ok. Now GarlandGreene made a valid point, and so did Tudor, please consider their advice

Comment: @Tudor unfortunately am using framework 3.5, not possible to perform migration to 4.0 framework

Comment: for instance, yes. Whenever you use multiple threads, make sure that all objects accessed by more than a single thread at one time are thread safe - or create a thread-safe access for them using a lock()

Comment: @GarlandGreene, Thanks for the note, i'll try this and update you :)

Comment: 1) _" SOMETIMES, i get a null reference exception"_  - that fits with a race-condition, most likely in `results.AddRange()`.

Comment: I understand now its not safe that many threads write into the same collection simultaneously, but is it okay for many threads to READ from the same collection simultaneously ?

Comment: 2) `Thread.Abort()` should be avoided. It looks OK here but I wouldn't want to run the risks.

Comment: @HenkHolterman alternative suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one obvious problem is here:

```
results.AddRange(result);
```

where you're updating a list from multiple threads. Try using a lock:

```
object resultsLock = new object(); // globally visible
...
lock(resultsLock) 
{
    results.AddRange(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug is correctly found in the chosen answer although I do not agree with the answer.   You should switch to using a concurrent collection. In your case a ConcurrentBag or ConcurrentQueue. Some of which are (partially) lockfree for better performance. And they provide more readable and less code since you do not need manual locking.

Your code would also more than halve in size and double in readability if you keep from manually created threads and manual paritioning;

```
Parallel.ForEach(objects, MyObjectProcessor);

public void MyObjectProcessor(Object o)
{
  // Create result and add to results
}
```

Use a ParallelOptions object if you want to limit the number of threads with Parallel.ForEach............

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem in results = null

```
while (allThreads.Values.Any(th => th.IsAlive))
    { if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 60000) { results = null;  allThreads.Values.ToList().ForEach(t => t.Abort());
```

if the threads not finised faster than 60000 ms you results become equal null and you can't call results.OrderBy(r => r.ZBox.Name).ToList(); it's throws exception

you should add something like that

```
if (results != null) 
  return  results.OrderBy(r => r.ZBox.Name).ToList();
else
  return null;
```

Comment: Am sorry i should've mentioned that i modified the code due to code safety reasons before i posted it, this condition is already take into consideration. Thanks for the note i'll update this in the question.

Comment: @TonyTheLion i'll look around for the WaitAll method ;)